# Move drawable right to left on EditText focus

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to move my icon from right side of EditText to left side (animating) when focused on EditText. Also I need to put another icon in place of drawable right.

[image]

Here is my XML layout so far

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    tools:context="com.example.SearchActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/barSearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/search_bar"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_search_white"
        android:drawingCacheQuality="high"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:lines="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Also, when I start the activity, EditText is out of focus, if I click on it it gets in focus but when I click somwere else or click back button I want to loose focus. If I click back button, keyboard desapears but EditText stays in focus.

Does anybody know what is the proper way to achieve this.

Comment: For updating the icons on your edittext I would suggest using the setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds() method. But the change occurs immediately.

Answer (score 0):

try this.....

```
// Set drawables for left, top, right, and bottom - send 0 for nothing

editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.drawableRight, 0);
```